# form.map is not a function error, only appearing after getting data from an input field

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am trying to get data from input fields and add the values to a list to send as a post request.

I have a form object

```
const [form, setForm] = useState([
    {
        hole1: 1,
        par1: '',
        stroke1: '',
        yards1: ''
    },
    {
        hole2: 2,
        par2: '',
        stroke2: '',
        yards2: ''
    },

//repeat for 18 holes
```

Then when I click the submit button after filling in the form,

```
const list = form.map((holes, i) => {
            const num = i +1;
            return {
                
              hole: num,
              par: holes[`par${num}`],
              stroke: holes[`stroke${num}`],
              yards: holes[`yards${num}`],
              course: {
                courseid: 3,
              },
            };
          });
```

If the form is empty this works fine and if I log the `list`

```
0: {hole: 1, par: '', stroke: '', yards: '', course: {…}}
1: {hole: 2, par: '', stroke: '', yards: '', course: {…}}
2: {hole: 3, par: '', stroke: '', yards: '', course: {…}}
```

As soon as I enter some values into the form though, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: form.map is not a function`

I understand `form` needs to be an `array` to use the `map` function, but I cannot figure out why it is working when the form is empty, but as soon as I add data it breaks? Is the data type changing when I add data?

edit,

Code for my onChange method which sets the values in the form.

```
const onChange = (event) => {
    const { value, name } = event.target;

  
      setForm((previousForm) => {
        return {
          ...previousForm,
          [name]: value
        };
      });
  
      setErrors((previousErrors) => {
        return {
          ...previousErrors,
          [name]: undefined
        };
      });
    };
```

Comment: can you add code where you use your `setForm` to set new state?

Comment: @StefanZivkovic I have added it to the question. THanks

Comment: In `setForm` you turn your array into an object

Comment: you don't set your next (new) state in valid/expected way.

Comment: @StefanZivkovic any advice on how I should do this properly? I am from a Java background and just getting started with react / JS

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan what is the correct way to setForm and keep it as an array?

Comment: it is not easy to say, the best would be that you post your complete code, or as much as it is relevant for resolving your doubts. Then community can help you.

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example